# Equivalent for 'Clone in git' in ClearCase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

I am new to ClearCase (just started Today), I used GIT and SVN before for version control.
In Git, I generally 'clone' the repository to fetch the code to my local and do the 'checkout'

What is the equivalent for it in ClearCase?
I read the document (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.1?topic=software-cleartool) but there is no clear definition for 'clone' and 'checkout'

Any help on this is appreciated and will be helpful for many!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I detailed general equivalences between Git and ClearCase in "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)" (2009)

Second, there is no direct equivalent for [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), since a clone would get (with default settings) the *full* history of a remote repository, which is never done with ClearCase: you don't get the full copy of a VOB (Versioned Object Base). Said Vob can be as large as many terabyte!

In ClearCase:

- you create a [**view** (snapshot, dynamic or web view)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm)
- you configure its config spec in order to select the versions of each file/folder you want to see in this view.

  - automatic configuration through UCM views, which derives their selection rules from the stream foundation baselines of each UCM components, meaning of each VOB root component folder,
  - or manual configuration for non-UCM view, where you specify whatever path and rules you want through config spec.

Note: the term checkout is a loaded one.

- in Git, it has been judged [too confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), and replaced with:

  - [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), to restore files at a certain version
  - [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) (to switch branches, which is done in ClearCase by modifying the config spec of an existing view, or by creating another view alltogether)
- in ClearCase, [`cleartool checkout`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=ucm-checkout) is used to mark a file for modification, and lock its state, before releasing the lock with a [`cleartool checkin`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=ucm-checkin).
  There is no need for such a pessimist lock with Git: you modify and commit locally whatever you want, and push later to the remote repository.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have already created the view but could you tell us what is the way (using Linux command) to pull the code to my local ?

Comment: @Harry What view did you create? A snapshot one? A dynamic one, a web one?

Comment: Created web and dynamic one

Comment: @Harry Is it an UCM view based on a stream, or just a regular dynamic view, with cleartool mkview?

Comment: Dynamic view with clear tool mkview

Comment: @Harry By default, a regular dynamic view shows the latest versions of the main branch of the mounted Vob(s), ... provided that you have Vob mounted: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=vobs-mounting-from-command-line-unix. Thenk check `ls /view/MyView/vobs/MyVob`

Comment: I accepted your answer, When I filter using the command : ct lsview -properties -full {myviewname}, I am able to find my view BUT I am not able to find my view under the folder /view/ so How to add the my view under the folder /view/ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240788/discussion-between-vonc-and-harry).